# How to output the value of one column in variables into

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a query that returns data in this form:

```
| ID |
+----+
| 25 |
| 28 |
```

The request will always return 2 value
For example, I need to pull the data (25,28) value into a variable, that is, into
Request :

```
select  ID  from table1
where CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id := iId
```

I Tried through pivot

```
with BaseData as (select  ID, CODE  from table1
where CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id := iId)
select * from  BaseData 
PIVOT
(
  MAX(ID)
  FOR CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty')
)
```

But how to derive the meaning of id on into here?
I Need a query like:

```
select  ID as id1,
        ID as id2
        into bId, pID
into  from table1
    where CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id := iId
```

Comment: you could retrieve it through procedure with help of out variables

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. There are no variables in Oracle SQL you can read values into. There are variables in Oracle's programming language PL/SQL. Are you writing PL/SQL (a function, procedure, trigger, package, ...)? What do you want to do with the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One variable per code. Either use two queries or use conditionel aggrgation.

### Two queries

```
create procedure p(iid integer) as
  bid integer;
  pid integer;
begin
  select id into bid 
  from table1 
  where code = 'bonus' and dcl_id = iid;

  select id into pid 
  from table1 
  where code = 'Pnlty' and dcl_id = iid;
end;
```

### Conditional aggregation

```
create procedure p(iid integer) as
  bid integer;
  pid integer;
begin
  select
    max(case when code = 'bonus' then id end),
    max(case when code = 'Pnlty' then id end)
  into bid, pid
  from table1 
  where code in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id = iid;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there

```
with BaseData as (
  select  ID, CODE  
  from table1
  where CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id = did
)
select 'bonus', 'Pnlty'
into bid, pid
from  BaseData
PIVOT
(
  MAX(ID)
  FOR CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Procedure Delivery_Region
  (
    iId in  varchar2,
    bId     out number,
    pID     out number,
  ) is
  begin
     select  ID as id1,
            ID as id2
            into bId, pID
    into  from table1
        where CODE in ('bonus', 'Pnlty') and dcl_id = iId  
        end;
        end Delivery_Region;
```

You could place it one of your package and compile it then you will get your two different value through procedure.